# Possible 2nd storyboard to support slightly different interface in iOS 7?

Tags: ios6, storyboard, ios7

I created an interface for iOS 6 to have a similar appearance to iOS 7 before it shipped but now that 7 is out I want to support it natively. Some of the elements in the interface for 7 would replace other elements from 6 (i.e. a UIToolbar from 7 would replace a custom UIView from 6). How would I best go about this? Should I create a second storyboard to load conditionally depending on the iOS that is installed on the device?

Thanks for the help!